# Sometimes ios app takes too long to launch and crashes

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have figured out that this happens because app is taking too long to launch but I have not been able to rectify the issue.

I tried moving the sdk initialisation to a separate thread but even that doesnt work.The only major thing happening on the main thread in applicationDidFinishLaunching is initialisation of window:

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let exampleViewController: OnboardingViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("onboarding") as! OnboardingViewController
 self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This is the crash log generated on device:

> Version:             2 (1.6) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:      launchd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzzzY.png)
>
> Date/Time:           2015-12-07 17:08:34.34 +0530 Launch Time:
>   2015-12-07 17:08:06.06 +0530 OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
>   Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash) Highlighted by
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   com.what.whatever failed to launch after 20.00s
>   (launchIntent: foreground-interactive)
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.590 (user 2.590, system 0.000), 6%
>   CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.004, 0% CPU
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0: 0   dyld                            0x00000001200f8d10
>   0x1200d4000 + 150800 1   dyld
>     0x00000001200f8714 0x1200d4000 + 149268 2   dyld
>     0x00000001200e73d8 0x1200d4000 + 78808 3   dyld
>     0x00000001200ea4e4 0x1200d4000 + 91364 4   dyld
>     0x00000001200e63b8 0x1200d4000 + 74680 5   dyld
>     0x00000001200d7850 0x1200d4000 + 14416 6   dyld
>     0x00000001200dbdbc 0x1200d4000 + 32188 7   dyld
>     0x00000001200dbc88 0x1200d4000 + 31880 8   dyld
>     0x00000001200db978 0x1200d4000 + 31096 9   dyld
>     0x00000001200db430 0x1200d4000 + 29744 10  dyld
>     0x00000001200daf2c 0x1200d4000 + 28460 11  dyld
>     0x00000001200d7364 0x1200d4000 + 13156 12  dyld
>     0x00000001200d702c 0x1200d4000 + 12332 13  dyld
>     0x00000001200dbf1c 0x1200d4000 + 32540 14  dyld
>     0x00000001200e3d84 0x1200d4000 + 64900 15  dyld
>     0x00000001200e3228 0x1200d4000 + 61992 16  dyld
>     0x00000001200d8c94 0x1200d4000 + 19604 17  dyld
>     0x00000001200d9bb4 0x1200d4000 + 23476 18  dyld
>     0x00000001200d5044 0x1200d4000 + 4164
>
> No thread state (register information) available

So i tried profiling the app using instruments and the app is just stuck on the launch screen for over a minute and time profiler shows nothing. After a minute the app launches and works fine. I am unable to see the symbols in the time profiler too. Image attached below.

[image: Image showing time profiler]

Comment: There is another major thing happening - your `OnboardingViewController` gets initialised. Can you show its code?

Comment: The onboarding view controller's initialisation would just intialise variables.. Even if it is loaded then also it has no network requests in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Are there any files being read? What about 'viewWillAppear:' or other VC lifetime methods?

Comment: The shown code cannot be the problem. I do it this way all the time.

Comment: The error message indicates that the app took over 20 s to launch, so the system jettisoned it. Can you run profiler to see which line in your app takes the time? Are you doing any work on other threads? What kind?

Comment: I ran profiler and it shows 2 threads but without any symbols.. I even tried to  import symbols manually, didn't work.. However once the app lauches after taking some time I can see the symbols but it's too late by then.

Comment: @MirekE The image of time profiler running is added now.

Comment: i've seen a question on stackoverflow, and it was related to loading of custom fonts. Do you have them ?

Comment: I have custom fonts. I will remove them and check what happens.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods + many libraries ? could be the frameworks loading that is too slow.

Comment: Please how was this issue resolved? I'm facing the same with one of my App.

Thanks.